# If $F(xy^2,z-2x)=0$ then prove $x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial z}{\partial y }.\frac{y}{2}=2x$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

If $F(xy^2,z-2x)=0$ then prove $$x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial z}{\partial y }.\frac{y}{2}=2x$$
how can we get this expression ? and I don't understand what use of $F?$ I can substitute $xy^2$ and $z-2x$ and then try differentiation but that doesn't seem viable here since it will add 2 more variable which maybe unnecessary?

Comment: What is $F$?  If it can be anything, then the problem is clearly false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship $F(xy^2,z-2x)=0$ implicitly defines $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$. Differentiating gives:
\begin{align*}
0&=y^2F_1+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}-2\right)F_2,\\
0&=2xyF_1+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}F_2
\end{align*}
where $F_1$ and $F_2$ are, respectively, the partial derivatives of $F$ with respect to its first input and second input. When we multiply the first equality above by $2x$ and the second by $y$, the equality of the coefficients of $F_2$ implies
$$
2x\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}-2\right)=y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\iff x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}-\frac{y}{2}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=2x.
$$

Comment: What is $F_x$ and $F_y$ ?

Comment: @Tesla: partial derivatives of $F$ w.r.t to its first and second components. Let me edit for better notation. I also fixed a previous error of mine just now.

Comment: Doesn't seem to hold for $F(u,v)=u$.  Like I said, if $F$ is allowed to be anything, then the problem is false.

Comment: @Batominovski Of course, the solution predicates on being able to divide by $F_2$. Your $F$ has $F_2=0$ so this approach doesn't work. However,    it's easy enough to impose the additional assumptions to make the approach works. My working assumption is that the OP's problem has enough implicit assumptions to ensure that the desired equality holds.